# Unprovable theorem forall A : Prop, ~~A -> A

Tags: logic, coq

I am stuck with a theorem and I think that it's unprovable.

```
Theorem double_negation : forall A : Prop, ~~A -> A.
```

Can you prove it or explain why it is unprovable?

Is it due to Gödel's incompleteness theorems?

Comment: Such a simple and direct statement has nothing to do with Godel's incompleteness theorems.

Comment: Unfortunately this question is off-topic; it's not a programming question, and more of a theory question.

Comment: @DavidMakogon Can you point me to a place where I can get an answer?

Comment: @DavidMakogon this question is on-topic.  The question asks "is it possible to write a program with such-and-such properties, and how or why not?"  Would you mark a question "is it possible to write a Turing machine in C++ templates?" as off-topic in C++?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Double negation elimination is [not provable in constructive logic](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/153186/double-negation-elimination-in-constructive-logic) which underpins Coq. Attempting to prove it we quickly get [stuck](https://www.cs.cornell.edu/courses/cs3110/2017fa/l/20-coq-logic/notes.v):

```
Theorem double_negation_elim : forall A : Prop, ~~A -> A.
Proof.
  unfold not.
  intros A H.
  (* stuck because no way to reach A with H : (A -> False) -> False *)
Abort.
```

We can [show](https://www.reddit.com/r/logic/comments/5cl8d8/does_double_negation_elimination_implies_law_of/) that if double negation elimination was provable then Law of Excluded Middle would hold, that is, `(forall (A : Prop) , (~~A -> A)) -> forall A : Prop, A \/ ~A.`

First we [prove](https://sympa.inria.fr/sympa/arc/coq-club/2015-09/msg00016.html) intermediate result `∼∼(A ∨ ∼A)`:

```
Lemma not_not_lem: forall A: Prop, ~ ~(A \/ ~A).
Proof.
  intros A H.
  unfold not in H.
  apply H.
  right.
  intro a.
  destruct H.
  left.
  apply a.
Qed.
```

Therefore

```
Theorem not_not_lem_implies_lem: 
  (forall (A : Prop) , (~~A -> A)) -> forall A : Prop, A \/ ~A.
Proof.
  intros H A.
  apply H.
  apply not_not_lem.
Qed.
```

But this is a contradiction as LEM does not hold in constructive logic.